# Resize slider image to screen size [jquery cycle plugin]

Tags: jquery, css, cycle

I am trying to resize the slider image to the screen size , i tried using 100% width but still cant get the slider image to width 100% screen size , I am using jquery [cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) for slider. The test website is on [Testwebsite](http://selectinteriors.tangent-design.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a fullscreen image working responsively, I'd suggest looking at the [MaxImage](http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/2.0/) plugin. As that page state, no need to reinvent the wheel. So, it's just a case of calling the additional plugin and changing your code from:

```
$('#slides').cycle({...
```

to:

```
$('#slides').maximage({...
```